# vue dynamic async component set props with javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some code similar to below where i am importing a component dynamically and then i want to set some props on it.
I dont have a `<component></component>` html tag as i am passing the component to a 3rd party plugin that will display the component inside their own component.

the below code works but then i have started seeing the following vue warning error in the console:

```
option "propsData" can only be used during instance creation with the `new` keyword.
```

structure of settings variable:

```
const settings = {
    props:{
        title: "new title"
    }
}
```

component loading function:

```
function Load(compName, settings){
    import("@/"+ compName +".vue").then((mod)=>{                
            let mycomponent = mod.default;                                 
            const props = settings.props;

            mycomponent.propsData = {...props});

            //3rd party package needs this format
            let template = function(){
                return {template : mycomponent};
            }
            //not shown - code that passes the template variable to the 3rd party package
    });
}
```

is there another way to get the props into the component - or is it ok to ignore this warning?